# How to map left side of Either with two different types erros with Validation and DomainError

Tags: java, spring-boot, validation, vavr

I need help with Vavr in Java.
I have a business process to update a book entity and I want to make validations before every update.

Steps:

1. Request from RestController with Data to make Update as `BookUpdateDto`.
2. Try to find `BookById`; return Book if exists or return Either with `BOOK_NOT_FOUND`.
3. I make mapping from `BookUpdateDto` to `BookCreateDto` and validate.
4. My validation return `Validation<Seq<String>, BookCreateDto>` and that's my problem.
5. My question is: How I could pack my errors from validation with business error when a book does not exist?

```
public Either<BookError, BookCreateDto> updateBookById(final Long bookId, final BookUpdateDto toUpdate) {
        return findBookById(bookId)
                .toEither(BOOK_NOT_FOUND)
                .map(Book::response)
                .map(bookValidation::validate)
                
     

                .map(book -> book.mapToUpdate(toUpdate))
                .map(book -> book.update(toUpdate))
                .map(book -> bookRepository.save(book).response());
    }
```

I do not know how to map my errors from validation and domain error that `BOOK_NOT_FOUND` in empty space in code. Or maybe my architecture to solve my problem is wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like `Validation.toEither` combined with a `flatMap` could do the trick.

The toEither changes the `Validation` into an `Either<List<String>, BookCreateDto>` and the `mapLeft` on that either changes the left side of the either from `List<String>` to a `BookError`.

```java
public Either<BookError, BookCreateDto> updateBookById(final Long bookId, final BookUpdateDto toUpdate) {
    return findBookById(bookId)
        .toEither(BOOK_NOT_FOUND)
        .map(Book::response)
        .map(bookValidation::validate)

        // This should perform the desired conversion
        .flatMap(validation -> validation.toEither().mapLeft(this::validationErrorsToBookError))

        .map(book -> book.mapToUpdate(toUpdate))
        .map(book -> book.update(toUpdate))
        .map(book -> bookRepository.save(book).response());
}
```

The `validationErrorsToBookError` would be a function that is responsible for turning a list of validations into a `BookError`. Probably something along these lines:

```java
BookError validationErrorsToBookError(Seq<String> validationErrors) {
    // Use logic that would fit your specific needs for BookErrors
    return new BookError(validationErrors.mkString(";"));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks great, but my BookError is enum with message error and http code.
I will try to solve it. Thank you so much!

Comment: I think you meant to leave a comment on @Hinse ter Schuur's answer, rather than post another answer to your own question..?